# Next.js 13 Error occurred prerendering page

Tags: next.js13

i have this page in my next app

```
    import React, { FC } from 'react';
    import Link from 'next/link';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { MenuType } from '@/libs/types';
    import { cn } from '@/libs/utils';
    
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/categories`
      );
      if (response.status === 500) {
        throw new Error('Failed');
      }
      return response.data;
    };
    
    const MenuPage = async () => {
      const menu: MenuType = await getData();
    
      return (
        <div className='p-4 flex flex-col  h-[calc(100vh-6rem)] md:h-[calc(100vh-9rem)] md:flex-row items-center lg:px-20 xl:px-40'>
          {menu.map((category) => (
            <Link
              href={`/menu/${category.slug}`}
              key={category.id}
              className='w-full h-1/3 bg-cover p-8 md:h-1/2'
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${category.image})` }}
            >
              <div className={`text-${category.color} w-1/2 h-full  flex flex-col`}>
                <h1 className='uppercase font-bold text-3xl'>{category.title}</h1>
                <p className='text-sm my-8'>{category.description}</p>
                <button
                  className={cn(
                    'hidden 2xl:block py-2 px-4 rounded-md mt-auto w-fit font-semibold text-green-500 bg-white',
                    {
                      'text-white': category.color === 'black',
                      'bg-black': category.color === 'black'
                    }
                  )}
                >
                  Explore
                </button>
              </div>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    };

export default MenuPage;
```

Now the problem comes when I try to run npm run build. I think it has to do with the page somehow trying to call the API before the server is running. I looked up the documentation and tried some of the solutions mentioned here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error. The error I'm seeing is: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80.' and Error occurred prerendering page /menu But nothing seems to help. Now the problem goes away if I simply don't call the API. It's weird because some of my other pages also call my server API just like this one.

Also the app works fine in dev mode but when i try to deploy it to vercel i get thos erros